# Image is not shown in the popup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vite

Using the starter template https://github.com/antfu/vitesse-webext for creating chrome extension. I tried to show an image in the popup but its not resolved properly. I have put the pass.png at same location as Popup.vue

Popup.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="w-[300px] px-4 py-5 text-center text-gray-700">
    <Logo />
    <div>WebExt <span class="opacity-50">v. 1.0</span></div>
    <p class="mt-2">
      Some description here...
      <img src="./pass.png" />
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

When clicking the icon to show the popup, its not resolved and the code shown like
[image]
[image]

Edit: Event if I use `<img src="pass.png" />` its not resolved

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
<img src="pass.png">
```

Comment: Nope, its not resolved! You can try to download the starter-template and try quickly

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try out to import it then bind it to the img src :

```html
<template>
  <div class="w-[300px] px-4 py-5 text-center text-gray-700">
    <Logo />
    <div>WebExt <span class="opacity-50">v. 1.0</span></div>
    <p class="mt-2">
      Some description here...
      <img :src="imgUrl" />
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup >
import imgUrl from './pass.png'

</script
```